# Implementing Luhn's Algo in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

Is it possible (I believe so, especially with strings.lib) to implement Luhn's Algorithm (the math function that confirms all 16 digits of a credit card are valid) in a solidity function without severe gas costs for strings manipulations?

Here is a js example of Luhn's Algo - I'm a bit lost on best place to start in solidity.

```
// Takes a credit card string value and returns true on valid number
function valid_credit_card(value) {
  // Accept only digits, dashes or spaces
    if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)) return false;

    // The Luhn Algorithm. It's so pretty.
    let nCheck = 0, bEven = false;
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

    for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
              nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

        if (bEven && (nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;

        nCheck += nDigit;
        bEven = !bEven;
    }

    return (nCheck % 10) == 0;
}
```

Questions I have:

- String, bytes, or uint? (for gas costs)
- Assembly or string library? (for gas costs)
- optimization of math functions for gas
- Anyway to not use a loop?

Would love to see some starting points if anyone has any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I convert your code into solidity language.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >0.8.1;

contract Luhn {
  
   /// @title Lunh Algorithim implementation
   /// @author Atarpara
   /// @notice is a simple checksum formula used to validate a variety of identification numbers, such as credit card numbers, IMEI numbers, Canadian Social Insurance Numbers.
   /// @return ture or false 
   function luhnalgo(string calldata _number) public pure returns(bool){
      bytes memory c = bytes(_number);
      uint length = c.length;
      uint8 sum = 0;
      uint8 zero = 48;
      bool _a = false;

    for(uint i = length ; i > 0 ; i--){
          uint8 temp = uint8(c[i-1]);

          if(temp < 47  && temp > 58){
            revert("Your Card Number is Invalid");
          }

          uint8 d = temp - zero;
          if(_a && (d <<= 1) > 9){
            d -= 9;
          }
          sum += d % 10;
         _a = !_a;
      } 
     return (sum%10==0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented a slim version which does not check the input for the correct format. it just expect numbers like 49927398716 or 1234567812345670. also, you pass the number as a sequence of bytes. by example if you want to check:

- "49927398716" you need to pass "0x0409090207030908070106"
- "1234567812345670" you need to pass "0x01020304050607080102030405060700"

  ```
   function valid_credit_card(bytes memory value) external returns (bool){
   // The Luhn Algorithm. It's so pretty.
   uint256 nCheck = 0;
   bool bEven = false;

   for (uint256 n = value.length; n > 0; n--) {
       uint256 nDigit = uint256(uint8(value[n-1]));
       if (bEven && (nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;

       nCheck += nDigit;
       bEven = !bEven;
   }
   return (nCheck % 10) == 0;
  }
  ```